# Number of nondecreasing functions from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

> How many functions $$f: \{1,2,\dots,n\} \to \{1,2,\dots,n\}$$ are there such that for every $i \leq j$ we have $f(i) \leq f(j)$?

The only way I could think of was removing all the "bad" cases from $n^n$, but that wouldn't be very effective. What better way could I use?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A001700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

From [here](http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~animeshm/ds/tut4_sol.pdf).
Also, removing "bad" cases from total cases is not always a good idea.